# How to I search for files recursively while updating a progress bar and returning the file List to the application from BackgroundWorker

Tags: vb.net, search, recursion, backgroundworker, vb.net-2010

Thanks for reading!

I am currently trying to develop an application which will backup large folders to a specified  destination. To find all the files in the specified 'backup' directory I am using the following code.

```
Public Shared Function GetFilesRecursive(ByVal initial As String) As List(Of String)

    Dim result As New List(Of String)
    Dim stack As New Stack(Of String)
    stack.Push(initial)

    Do While (stack.Count > 0)

        Dim dir As String = stack.Pop
        Try

            result.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.*"))


            Dim directoryName As String
            For Each directoryName In Directory.GetDirectories(dir)
                stack.Push(directoryName)
            Next

        Catch ex As Exception
            'stay quiet
        End Try
    Loop


    Return result

End Function
```

From here I am using BackgroundWorker to copy each file and report the progress of the completed list to the GUI via a progress bar.

This is fine and works great until I come to a large directory, say C:\Windows where it hangs and freezes the GUI until it completes, this is horrible!

I have tried putting my GetFilesRecursive function into a separate background worker to run first so I can update the GUI however I am struggling on how to return the List of found files back to my application (I get cross-threading exception) and how to update the progress bar to show the progress of the GetFileRecursive function so the user knows it is processing the list of files and has not crashed/frozen.

Thank you very much in advance for your input! :)

Steve

Comment: Post the code that actually does the copying. Cross-threading exceptions are extremely common for people new to threading, so we'll be able to quickly point out what needs to happen to avoid such errors.

Comment: Hi Charlie, Thanks for your reply - There is no exception in the copying bit, that background worker runs great. My problem is trying to basically get the above code in a background worker and return 'result' back to the application, currently I am *trying to do it with a global variable of the same type and simply, fileList = result. It really does not like this! - Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reference, here's the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) manual page.

First, have a look at the [RunWorkerAsync(Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f00zz5b2.aspx) method. With this method, you can pass an object to your 'worker' function. This might be an empty stack, for example.

In your [RunWorkerCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx) event handler, you can grab that same object (now populated with file paths) from the [RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.runworkercompletedeventargs.result.aspx) and do what you will with it. The reason I suggest passing an object is that you avoid the need for a static variable. In this case, a static variable is a bit of a code smell and should be avoided.

If you want to report the progress of the routine, you need to call the [ReportProgress(int)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4.aspx) function from within your worker function. This will fire the [ProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) event which you can use to drive your progress bar.

MSDN also has a pretty good example of the pattern [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hybbz6ke%28v=VS.80%29.aspx#Y0). They don't do anything to demonstrate progress reporting but there's an example of that on the ReportProgress page.

**Edit:**

If it's a plain `Stack` you're using, then I suggest creating the stack, then passing it to RunWorkerAsync( ). From here, you can get the stack from the event args of BackgroundWorker_DoWork, which you can *then* pass to your actual worker function, in this case, `GetFilesRecursive( )`. So `GetFilesRecursive( )` does not actually return anything, but it's able to fill the stack, which you can then access again from your ProgressCompleted handler. Mind you, you'll need to cast that object back to a `Stack` (or whatever type of object you decide to use) before you actually use it.

**Big picture**: the stack is like a bucket which you pass around, and gets filled. You first create the bucket when you call RunWorkerAsync( ), passing the bucket as an argument.

Comment: Hi Thanks again, I think I am almost there - Where do I populate the object? In Backgroundworker_DoWork? and how do I go about populating it? *EDIT* It's e.Argument and e.Result right?

Comment: Excellent - Thanks very much! I missed the fact you could pass an argument to RunWorkerAsync - Going to do some more reading - thanks for your links. It's all working perfectly now, good man! :)

Comment: Glad I could help. If you still have problems with cross-threading exceptions, do a search for `InvokeRequired`. There are a bunch of common patterns you can use. I didn't mention it in the answer as technically it's a separate issue, I think. Basically, if you try to access a control (like a progress bar for example) from a different thread from the thread the control was created on, you'll have problems. InvokeRequired is true when you need to switch threads. With the BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged event, though, you might not have problems with it.

Comment: Alright, i'll keep that in mind - i'm sure it will help, thanks again!